# Trying to extract mailing lists from .pck file

Tags: mailing-list, mailman

In short, our admin left our organization without properly handing over his duties and we don't have a replacement specialist yet. For some reason, the mail server stopped working and we don't have access to our mailboxes, but this is not the main problem, the immediate problem is that we don't have access to our mailing lists.

We have a backup of our mail server and there is a folder named lists which contains folders with the names of our mailing lists, each folder has 4 files "config.pck" "config.pck.last", "pending.pck", "request.pck".

I'm guessing that the lists are in one of these files, but I can't figure out how to convert/open them.

I can be wrong, but we use Mailman as mail server.

As you may have noticed I'm very far away from IT.

Any help will be appreciated.

I tryed to open these files in text editor but they are unreadble.